# Select con opción selected según un foreach

Tags: php, html, mysql, foreach, select2

Tengo un select que se construye recorriendo un array en php.
El caso es que quiero que si coincide el id del value con una variable de session en php ponga el texto select para que se quede marcada por defecto.

Tengo este código pero por alguna razón que se me escapa me mete el selected en todas las opciones del array.

```
<?php foreach($Consulta as $Empresas) { ?>
  <option value="<?=$Empresas["id"];?>" <?php if ($Empresas["id"] == $_SESSION["Empresa_Id"]); { echo "selected"; } ?>><?=$Empresas["Nombre"]; ?></option>
<?php } ?>
```

la variable de session es un numero simple.

y la salida que me da este código es esta:

```
<select style="width: 262px;">
<option selected value="0">Todas</option>
<option value="2" selected>Empresa 2</option>
<option value="3" selected>Empresa 3</option>
<option value="10" selected>Empresa 10</option>
</select>
```

Con lo que se vuelve loco y el seleccionado que marca es el ultimo registro.

¿Que estoy haciendo mal?

Comment: Puedes usar var_dump($_SESSION["Empresa_Id"]); para ver que tiene la variable de sesión, asi mismo puedes colocar la condición dentro de un var_dump para ver si te esta devolviendo true o false, porque pareciera que siempre esta dando true, y no deberia ser el caso

Comment: @BryantJimenez da como resultado que hay 1 valor con el valor adecuado. string(1) "3" donde el 3 es la empresa. Menos mal que tu también piensas que debería estar bien XD, ya pensaba que estaba loco por no ver el fallo

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Quizás esta opción sugiere más líneas de código, pero queda mucho más legible tanto para tí como para futuros programadores.

Aquí la idea principal es separar el código en variables para identificar facilmente cada parte del mismo y depurar los posibles errores. Luego, si deseas, puedes volver a tus tres líneas.

```
//Inicializar, validar y concatenar variables
<?php
  $empresa = $_SESSION["Empresa_Id"]; 
  $listaEmpresas = '';
  foreach($Consulta as $Empresas) {
    $idEmpresa = $Empresas["id"];
    $nombreEmpresa = $Empresas["Nombre"];
    $selected = $idEmpresa == $empresa ? 'selected' : ''; 
    $listaEmpresas .= '<option value="'.$idEmpresa.'" '.$selected.'>'.$nombreEmpresa.'</option>';
  }
?>
//Luego en HTML, mostrar la variable con toda la lista, incluyendo la seleccionada
<select style="width: 262px;">
  <?=$listaEmpresas?>
</select>
```

Comment: Si bien la idea de armar el html en una cadena tiene valor, manejando así las variables duplicas memoria y lo haces mas complejo innecesariamente sin obtener una ganancia significativa en la legibilidad; el manejo de arreglos asociativos en PHP debes dominarlo, debe adentrarse hasta tu ADN. A veces la legibilidad mejora con simples espacios o usando [*cadenas formateadas*](https://www.php.net/manual/es/function.sprintf.php).

Comment: Asi, si funciona. Mil gracias... pero sigo sin entender donde tengo yo el fallo. A ver si consigo sacarlo gracias a tu código que si va...

Comment: solo usando la linea $selected = $idEmpresa == $empresa ? 'selected' : ''; ya funciona, pero no entiendo la construcción de la condición ¿sabes donde puedo documentarme de este tipo de condiciones?

Comment: Se le llama **operador ternario** y se usa para reemplazar el condicional `if...else`. Básicamente es una comparación. Si el id de la empresa que está iterando dentro del ciclo es igual al id de la empresa que está en la variable de sesión, se asigna la propiedad `selected` al `option`, en caso contrario se deja vacío. Puedes ampliar la información buscando en Google, así tal cual, [php operador ternario](https://www.google.com/search?q=php+operador+ternario&oq=php+operador+ternario&aqs=chrome..69i57j0i512l2j0i22i30j0i15i22i30i625j0i22i30l4.5905j0j7&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8)

Answer (score 0):

Algo que me percaté es que tienes un error de sintaxis, hay un `;` entre las llaves de tu validación, ya con esto quizás tu problema se solucione, debería quedar algo como:

```
<?php foreach($Consulta as $Empresas) { ?>
  <option value="<?=$Empresas["id"];?>" <?php if ($Empresas["id"] == $_SESSION["Empresa_Id"]) { echo "selected"; } ?>><?=$Empresas["Nombre"]; ?></option>
<?php } ?>
```

Comment: Mil gracias por tu respuesta, lo mismo al copiar el texto se me fue los dos puntos. He intentado cambiar la forma de construir la condición y tampoco. (Lo digo porque al cambiar la construcción los dos puntos habrían ido fuera. Pero te agradezco el detalle 